# Error compiling calculation in drools LHS

Tags: drools

I am having issues getting drools to compile a rule where a computation is performed in the LHS and the result compared to a static value. The facts I am working with are given to me and I have no control over them so please answer based on the classes as is as opposed to suggesting that the data model be changed.

```
public class Item {
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    private List<String> errors;
}

public class ItemFacts {
    private Item newItem;
    private Item existingItem;
}

rule "validatePrice"
when
   $itemFacts:itemFacts(newItem != null, newItem.attributes != null,
        $price:newItem.attributes["price"] != null,
        $price#BigDecimal.scale > 4 ||
        $price#BigDecimal.precision - $price.BigDecimal.scale > 9)
then
    itemFacts.errors.add("Invalid size for price attribute.");
end
```

The scale check compiles and works fine but the check that subtracts the scale from the precision to make sure there are not too many places to the left of the decimal will not compile. I also tried ´$price#BigDecimal.(precision - scale) > 9´ but that will not compile either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you find a syntax definition documenting *precisely* what you intend to write on that rule's LHS and RHS then please follow this documentation.

Meanwhile, give these constructs a wide berth and stay as close to Java as possible. Also, I suggest to put formulas into functions or static methods.

```
function boolean checkSize( BigDecimal bd ){
    return bd.scale() > 4 || bd.precision() - bd.scale() > 9;
}

rule "validatePrice"
when
    $itemFacts: ItemFacts(newItem != null, newItem.attributes != null,
    $price:newItem.attributes["price"] != null,
    checkSize( (BigDecimal)$price ))
then
    $itemFacts.getNewItem().getErrors().add("Invalid size for price attribute.");
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I still get a jkar compilation error on the line that executes the checkSize function. `[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.walmart.emi.rules.model.ItemFacts.checkSize(java.math.BigDecimal)]`

Comment: I moved the function to a Java utility class as a public static boolean method then imported the utility class and it compiled fine. I'm not fond of having the code spread out but at least it works. I will be spending the next hour or two creating and executing some unit tests. Wish me luck. :)